# upload image in php by its url

Tags: php, file-upload

i have this form to upload images:

```
<form method="post" action="upld.php" name="insertForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
Image name:<br />
<input type="text" name="iname" /><br />
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />

</form>
```

and here is the upld.php

```
<?php
$db_name = "DB_name";
$table_name = "tble";
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

 if  (($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0))
    {
echo "<h3> Error in File! </h3>";
    }
  else
    {
    if ((file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) )
      {
      echo "<h3> file not exsists!</h3>";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

//$id=mysql_insert_id();
$time=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time());
$img_name=$_POST['iname'];
$img=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$sql="INSERT INTO $table_name VALUES('{$img}','{$time}','{$img_name}')";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$connection);
mysql_close($connection);
echo "<h3>uploaded successfully</h3>";
}
}
}
echo "<br><br><a href='GalleryAdmin.php'>GO back to Admin Gallery</a>
";
?>
```

the problem is:

when i run it always say me file not exsist, acording to this if

```
 if ((file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) )
      {
      echo "<h3> file not exsists!</h3>";
```

i have the images folder with upld.php in the same folder

what would you guess is the problem?

Comment: Your question is hard to read due to the bad formatting. Maybe you can edit it and also add the form html code?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a slight logical error

```
file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])
```

Will return true if the file exists in the images folder (my guess would me if somebody already uploaded it). But, based on your log statement, what you want is

```
!file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])
```

Comment: if i take !file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]) just the other steps will execute without uploading

Comment: @user743473 I don't think you understand how uploads in PHP work...if you execute the code in the `else` block, it will work correctly (i.e the call to `move_uploaded_file` has to be called to move the upload out of the temporary folder into a permanent location).

Comment: can explain more i must check the images or the temp directory what is the code will be? as u say

Answer (score 2):

OK so you uploaded your file. But, what you checked was if it was in say "images/my.jpg". At this point its in tmp_name, in your tmp directory, most likely so, no it would always not exist at this point as the file is only in a temporary name, you need to check its in your temp location, move it, and then check if its in images surely?

Answer (score 1):

**First:**

PHP uploads the file to a temp directory. This is the file you need to move to your `images/` folder. You find the file in this location on your server:

```
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
```

This is the file on which you want to run file_exists to make sure the upload completed successfully. So:

```
if (file_exists($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) {
  // File upload successful. Now move file to your directory.
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  // Now do the database stuff here.
  // ... 
} else {
  // Nothing was uploaded and something is wrong!
}
```

**Secondary:**

Your code

```
file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])
```

will return TRUE, and therefore (in your code) it will say that there are no file. That's a logical error on your part.

Try:

```
!file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])
```

instead.

**Third:**

Make sure that the file to which you move the file (images/) have the proper chmod. It needs 775 for it to be possible to create files into. This is made via the ftp program.

Read more here: [CHMOD tutorial](http://www.phpjunkyard.com/tutorials/ftp-chmod-tutorial.php)

You will also need to move the file from the tmp dir to images before checking if it's there with file_exists.

Answer (score 0):

Please use move_uploaded_file before you check if the file exists;)

Otherwise try this:

1.) error_reporting(E_ALL);

2.) chmod the images directory (775), right mouse click on directory